# passing argurments to a decorator in python

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am using retry function from the package [**retrying**](https://pypi.org/project/retrying/). I want to pass the arguments of the **`retry`** decorator from a function and I am not sure how to achieve that.

```
@retry # (wait_exponential_multiplier=x,wait_exponential_max=y)
def post(url, json, exponential_multiplier, exponential_max):
    ...
    return(abc)
```

I want to pass the arguments of **`retry`** when calling the **`post()`**. I know when the **`function`** is compiled, the resulting **`function`** object is passed to the **`decorator`** so I am not sure if this is possible- or if I should may be approach it differently.

Comment: So what you want is to have the `post` function have the signature `post(url, json, wait_exponential_multiplier, exponential_max)`?

Comment: ah yes, will edit it right now. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to use the library as is, then you cannot really use the decorator like this. It's arguments are constant from when it is invoked (excepting messing about with mutable arguments). Instead, you could always invoke the decorator before calling the function each time. This allows you to change the retrying arguments as and when you need to.

eg.

```
def post(url, json):
    ...

rety(post, wait_exponential_multiplier=...)(url=..., json=...)
```

But at that point, you might as well just skip the decorator altogether, and use what the decorator is using.

```
from retrying import Retrying

def post(url, json):
    ...

Retrying(wait_exponential_multiplier=...).call(post, url=..., json=...)
```

Either of these ways allow you to keep the `post` function pure and abstracted away from the concept of retrying (making it easier to call `post` when you don't want retrying behaviour).

You could also write a convenience function that wrapper that fills in defaults for your program. eg.

```
def retrier(wait_exponential_multiplier=2, **kwargs):
    return Retrying(wait_exponential_multiplier=wait_exponential_multiplier, **kwargs)

retrier(wait_exponential_max=10).call(post, url=..., json=...)
retrier(wait_exponential_multiplier=3, wait_exponential_max=10).call(post, url=..., json=...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking there no *good* ways to achieve this. You surely can write code like this:

```
def post(url, json):
    ...
    return(abc)

...
decorated_func = retry(wait_exponential_max=1)(post)
a = decorated_func(url, json)
```

and it will work. But it looks rather ugly and will construct decorated object for every call ("regular" decorators are executed once in import time).

If decorator itself is not very complex - you can use this approach in some more user-friendly manner:

```
def _post(url, json):
    return(abc)

def post(url, json, wait_exponential_max=None, **kwargs):
    return retry(wait_exponential_max=wait_exponential_max, **kwargs)(_post)(url, json)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new decorator which pass its **own** arguments down to the decorated function and transforms the function using the `retry` decorator:

```
def retry_that_pass_down_arguments(**decorator_arguments):
    def internal_decorator(f):
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            # Add the decorator key-word arguments to key-word arguments of the decorated function
            kwargs.update(decorator_arguments) 
            return retry(**decorator_arguments)(f)(*args, **kwargs) 
        return decorated_function
    return internal_decorator
```

Then you can just do:

```
@retry_that_pass_down_arguments(wait_exponential_multiplier=x, wait_exponential_max=y)
def post(url, json, exponential_multiplier=None, exponential_max=None):
    ...
    return(abc)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complement to Jundiaius's answers to show that you can even use the inspect module to correctly handle the signature of the decorated function:

```
def deco_and_pass(deco, **kwparams):
    """Decorates a function with a decorator and parameter.
The parameters are passed to the decorator and forwarded to the function
The function must be prepared to receive those parameters, but they will
be removed from the signature of the decorated function."""
    def outer(f):
        sig = inspect.signature(f)       # remove parameters from the function signature
        params = collections.OrderedDict(sig.parameters)
        for k in kwparams:
            del params[k]
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):      # define the decorated function
            kwargs.update(kwparams)      # add the parameters
            # and call the function through the parameterized decorator
            return deco(**kwparams)(f)(*args, **kwargs)
        inner.__signature__ = inspect.signature(f).replace(
            parameters = params.values())
        inner.__doc__ = f.__doc__        # update doc and signature
        return inner
    return outer
```

Example usage:

```
@deco_and_pass(retry,wait_exponential_multiplier=x,wait_exponential_max=y)
def post(url, json, exponential_multiplier, exponential_max):
    ...
    return(abc)
...
post(url, json)
```

The signature of the decorated function is only `def post(url, json)`

Limits: the above code only accepts and passes keyword arguments for the decorator